# How to type "ë" using shift+e? (as in US international layout Windows version)

Tags: keyboard

So here's the deal, I want to be able to type "ë" using shift+"+e. This can't be done with the keyboard layouts in elementary OS, I've tried changing it to US International and Alternative International but still I can't type "ë" easily. Does anyone know how to fix this or add keyboard layouts that correspond with the layout of windows version of US International?

Comment: This page may point you in the right direction: http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/choosers/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/35778/47206

Answer (score 2):

In Linux the layouts are not exactly the same as in Windows, I think, but for English US (if that is what you need) you have *English US alternative  International, English US International with dead keys, English US International Algr dead keys*.

*Dead keys are symbols that in order to be used have to be followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>; followed by other keys, they add [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) to these keys*; the dead-keys resemble the diacritics they trigger, and therefore are easy to remember: `"`+`a`=`ä`, `^`+`a`= `â`, etc.

---

**English US alternative  International** and  **English US International with dead keys** seem almost identical.

`"`, which is a dead key, followed by `e` gives `ë`

---

If you don't want to switch keyboards and use one that doesn't have those dead keys, you can try **English US International Algr dead keys**, where dead keys appear only with <kbd>Altgr</kbd>. There `ë` is done with  <kbd>Altgr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, as seen here:

[image]

---

As for `ë` made with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> I have not found any English US QWERTY layout that does that.